# Redis: Add to sorted set using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, redis, node-redis

I am trying to add a value to a sorted set in Redis using TypeScript like this `client.ZADD('test', 10, 'test')` but this throws an error

```
Argument of type '["test", 10, "test"]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[key: string, members: ZMember | ZMember[], options?: ZAddOptions | undefined] | [options: CommandOptions<ClientCommandOptions>, key: string, members: ZMember | ZMember[], options?: ZAddOptions | undefined]'.
  Type '["test", 10, "test"]' is not assignable to type '[options: CommandOptions<ClientCommandOptions>, key: string, members: ZMember | ZMember[], options?: ZAddOptions | undefined]'.
    Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'CommandOptions<ClientCommandOptions>'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ readonly [symbol]: true; }'.
```

Comment: Looks like `ZADD` accepts either a three arguments (`[key: string, members: ZMember | ZMember[], options?: ZAddOptions | undefined]`) or four (`[options: CommandOptions<ClientCommandOptions>, key: string, members: ZMember | ZMember[], options?: ZAddOptions | undefined]`). Assuming you want the three values one, is `10` compatible with `ZMember | ZMember[]` and `test` compatible with `ZAddOptions | undefined`?? TS is asumming you're going for the second signature and asks you to provide `CommandOptions<ClientCommandOptions>` as first parameter.

Comment: @doup tried doing this by importing ```commandOptions``` and updating ```client.ZADD('test', 10, 'test')``` to ```clinet.zAdd(commandOptions({}), 'test', 10, 'test')``` but i got this error ```Type '[CommandOptions<ClientCommandOptions>, "test", 10, "test"]' is not assignable to type '[options: CommandOptions<ClientCommandOptions>, key: string, members: ZMember | ZMember[], options?: ZAddOptions | undefined]'.
    Type at position 2 in source is not compatible with type at position 2 in target.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ZMember | ZMember[]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the redis types definitions files found in:

```
node_modules\@node-redis\client\dist\lib\commands\generic-transformers.d.ts
```

The interface definition for the type ZMember is the following:

```
interface ZMember {
    score: number;
    value: string;
}
```

So your function call should look like the following:

```
client.zAdd('test_list', { score: 10, value: 'test'})
```

Answer (score 1):

`client.ZADD('test', { member: 'test', score: 10 })` should to the trick